# React Apollo Query/Mutation Typescript

Tags: typescript, react-apollo

I need help trying to typescript a mutation and Query. The documentation and examples are limited and i'm struggling to manage to understand how to do it. I don't really understand the last property from the documentation. It seems to be input, response, variables, ?. https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/recipes/static-typing

query and mutation below where I had to use any:

````
interface Data {
  loading: DataValue<boolean> | undefined;
  isLinkValid: DataValue<boolean> | undefined;
}
interface InputProps {
  location: {
    search: string;
  };
  showToast: Function;
}
interface Variables {
  id: string | string[] | null | undefined;
}

const validateLinkQuery = graphql<InputProps, Data, Variables, Data>(VALIDATE_LINK_MUTATION, {
  options: ({ location }) => {
    const params = QueryString.parse(location.search);
    const id = params.id;
    return {
      variables: { id },
    };
  },
  props: ({
    ownProps,
    data,
  }: {
    ownProps: {
      showToast: Function;
    };
    data?: any;
  }) => {
    const { validateLink, loading, error } = data;
    if (error) {
      ownProps.showToast(
        Type.ERROR,
        get(error, 'graphQLErrors[0].message', 'An error occured on the validate link query')
      );
    }
    return {
      isLinkValid: validateLink,
      loading,
    };
  },
});



const validateUserMutation = graphql(
  VALIDATE_CARD_MUTATION,
  {
    props: ({ ownProps, mutate }) => ({
      validateCard: (access: SubmitAccessInput) =>
        mutate({
          variables: {
            access,
          },
        })
          .then((response: any) => response)
          .catch((error: any) => {
            ownProps.showToast(
              Type.ERROR,
              get(error, 'graphQLErrors[0].message', 'An error occurred while signing up for an account')
            );
          }),
    }),
  }
);```
````

Comment: Not able to understand what you mean by type definition for query or mutation. if you need type definition of mutation and query on the client side. They are a lot of ways.

Answer (score 2):

I would use https://github.com/dotansimha/graphql-code-generator library which generator type and React Apollo HOC component with type based on your graphql schema.

After you can do something like this.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Mutation } from "react-apollo";
import { gql } from "apollo-boost";
import { RouteComponentProps } from "react-router-dom";

import { LoginMutationVariables, LoginMutation } from "../../schemaTypes";
import { meQuery } from "../../graphql/queries/me";
import { userFragment } from "../../graphql/fragments/userFragment";
import { Form } from "./Form";

const loginMutation = gql`
  mutation LoginMutation($email: String!, $password: String!) {
    login(email: $email, password: $password) {
      ...UserInfo
    }
  }

  ${userFragment}
`;

export class LoginView extends React.PureComponent<RouteComponentProps<{}>> {
  render() {
    return (
      <Mutation<LoginMutation, LoginMutationVariables>
        update={(cache, { data }) => {
          if (!data || !data.login) {
            return;
          }

          cache.writeQuery({
            query: meQuery,
            data: { me: data.login }
          });
        }}
        mutation={loginMutation}
      >
        {(mutate, { client }) => (
          <Form
            buttonText="login"
            onSubmit={async data => {
              // optional reset cache
              await client.resetStore();
              const response = await mutate({
                variables: data
              });
              console.log(response);
              this.props.history.push("/account");
            }}
          />
        )}
      </Mutation>
    );
  }
}
```

Here LoginMutationVariables and LoginMutation type are being generated through graphql-code-generator.

`graphql-code-generator` also generate `React Apollo Mutation/Query Hoc component with type for all mutation and queries. So you don't even need to pass these type.  After generating HOC component, you can write same component like this

```
<LoginMutationComponent>
... rest of the code
</LoginMutationComponent>
```

rather than doing like this

```
<Mutation<LoginMutation, LoginMutationVariables>
```

But you need to configure graphql-code-generator. if you want to generate HOC component for queries and mutation

Comment: Thanks for this, I will give it a crack and get back to you with my solution if I can get it working.

Comment: Please let know if you have any problem with this. So I can help you